# border-bottom not working correctly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-float, grid-system

I have a strange problem, i have 3 tab menu items, that have text,after text i set up border-bottom, it's working fine for first-menu tab, but for other 2 it's appears over another border-bottom, but when i put code in Jsfiddle it's works correctly.. Here is my code [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kani339/4dL8qb0g/)

HTML

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <header>
                    <a href="#"><h1 class="title">Title</a><a href="#" id="show-about-btn">&#9650;</a></h1>
                </header>
                <div class="menu-nav">  
                    <nav class="subnav">
                        <ul class="tabs">
```

CSS

```
body {
    background-color: #E5E5E5;

}

a:link{
    text-decoration:none !important;
}

.title{
    margin-top: 150px;
    font-size: 450%;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.title a,
.title a:visited,
.title a:link {
    color: black;
}


.title a:hover,
.title a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #2bb673;
}

#show-about-btn {
    font-size: 40%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    color: #2bb673;
}


/*Navigation*/

.subnav {
    height: 80px;
    line-height: 3em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.subnav li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    padding: 1px 40px 1px 1px;
}

.subnav ul li a.active {
    padding: 6px;
    background-color: #2bb673;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -o-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.subnav li a {
    color: #2bb673;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: relative;
    right: 30px;
}

.subnav a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease-in;
    transition: all .3s ease-in;
}

article {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.tab {
    position: relative;
    top: 12px;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.menu-nav {
    display: none;
}

.tab p,h5{
    padding-bottom: 25px;
}

.tab h4 {
    margin-top: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.tab h5 {
    font-size:18px;
}

.tab img {
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

/*Content*/

.our-work a {
    font-family: "Literaturnaya Italic";
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 46px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    color: black;
}
```

At first screen border is in correct place

[image]

At the second tab, this same border appears over another
[image]

Comment: you have to reproduce the issue so that we can fix it

Comment: @J Santosh added screenshot, hope this will help

Comment: Probably you have more stylesheets and so CSS borrowed from elsewhere which is messing up your menu. You can view computed CSS (using chrome dev tools) and find out which rules are getting applied to your element and from where they are coming.

Comment: just add class `row` to `#about_us`.

bootstrap grid system classes like `.col-md-3` should always be wrapped inside `.row`.

Comment: @Pankaj Phartiyal, Thank You, added row, now everything works correclty

Comment: @Viktor answered separately :) please mark it as solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add class row to `#about_us` or better wrap your code under `#about_us` inside a `<div class="row">..content under #about_us..</div>`. Bootstrap grid system classes like `.col-md-3` should always be wrapped inside `.row` to avoid [CSS float problem](http://www.sitepoint.com/clearing-floats-overview-different-clearfix-methods/)

Mechanism

grid classes starting with `.col-` use `float:left` to get aligned one after other and maintain precise dimensions. So its parent will lose all height ([a classic CSS float problem](http://www.sitepoint.com/clearing-floats-overview-different-clearfix-methods/)). Now adding class `row` resolves this cleanly with adding a clearfix because it adds a pseudo element with `clear:both`.

```
.row:after {
content: " ";
clear:both;
display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is you have multiple styles as @pankajPhartiyal said.

remove this line from `border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;` from `article{}`  in styles section

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/00h6x3v2/)